# Отмена критерия фильтра при пустом значении критерия в формуле

Tags: google-spreadsheet, таблицы

В таблице на странице "Калькулятор" пытаюсь подсчитать количество строк по определенным критериям в ячейке(Е3) там забита формула:

```
=ROWS(FILTER('Расписание'!A3:V; MONTH('Расписание'!A3:A)=G2; IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B3)); 'Расписание'!P3:P=B3; ""); 'Расписание'!I3:I > 0; 'Расписание'!O3:O = A3))
```

Если в ячейке В3 есть выбранное значение (оно отвечает за фильтрацию в столбце Р) она отрабатывает правильно, а вот если пустое то нет пишет : "В результате выполнения функции FILTER ничего не обнаружено"

оно наверное и верно, потому что я задаю критерий фильтра в виде пустого значения, а мне необходимо что бы этого критерия просто не было( но что бы он был когда в В3 есть значение) и показалось количество строк со всеми возможными вариантами в столбце Р

ссылка на таблицу
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oncdaLr04kvcTOgEP4V1PrdJaYtMZEqYmO247MHaOoY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: =Формулу не нужно писать в проверяемом диапазоне, из-за этого возникает циклическая ссылка. Вынести нужно  в строку 1. =`MONTH('Расписание'!A3:A)=G2` -уже придумали новый месяц "Преподаватель"?

Comment: так G2 относится к другому листу - Калькулятор

Comment: Я о другой формуле. Формула в ячейке `Е3`на листе *Расписание*. С какого перепугу ссылки будут указывать на лист *Калькулятор*?

Comment: E3 на листе Калькулятор в описании вроде об этом написано

Answer (score 0):

вроде решил через условия и сильно разросшуюся формулу:

```
=IF(
    AND(Not(ISBLANK(B3)); Not(ISBLANK(C3)));
    ROWS(FILTER('Расписание'!A3:V; MONTH('Расписание'!A3:A)=G2; 'Расписание'!P3:P=B3; 'Расписание'!Q3:Q=C3; 'Расписание'!I3:I > 0; 'Расписание'!O3:O = A3));
    IF(AND((ISBLANK(B3)); Not(ISBLANK(C3)));
        ROWS(FILTER('Расписание'!A3:V; MONTH('Расписание'!A3:A)=G2; 'Расписание'!Q3:Q=C3; 'Расписание'!I3:I > 0; 'Расписание'!O3:O = A3));
        IF(AND(Not(ISBLANK(B3)); (ISBLANK(C3)));
            ROWS(FILTER('Расписание'!A3:V; MONTH('Расписание'!A3:A)=G2; 'Расписание'!P3:P=B3; 'Расписание'!I3:I > 0; 'Расписание'!O3:O = A3));
            IF(AND((ISBLANK(B3)); (ISBLANK(C3)));
                ROWS(FILTER('Расписание'!A3:V; MONTH('Расписание'!A3:A)=G2; 'Расписание'!I3:I > 0; 'Расписание'!O3:O = A3));
                "что-то не так"
            )
        )
    )
)
```